# Expecting identifier before leftbrace? ActionScript3

Tags: actionscript-3, identifier

```
package 
{

    import flash.display.*;

    dynamic public class SliderTrack_Terminator extends MovieClip
    {

        public function SliderTrack_Terminator()
        {
            return;
        }// end function

    }
}
```

this code returns this error :

```
ERROR: SliderTrack_Terminator.as, Line 7: Syntax error: expecting identifier before leftbrace.
```

Anyone know why this is returning an error? this is an error im getting with Sothinks SWF Quicker software.

Comment: I Think that you should just save your **as** script and recompile.

Comment: i did, same exact error log.

Comment: i was just having trouble getting the editor to get my code in correctly, thanks for the edit btw that is what my code looked like from the beginning.

Comment: I'll try this code with SWF Quicker ...

Comment: @akmozo it might be this wonky program, because no matter what i do with the code i get the same error. i looking into how this program its recompiling and where exactly to after it opens. i have a feeling any edits im doing are not being loading when im recompiling.

Comment: that would be very helpfull thank you @akmozo

Comment: Close all and then reopen and recompile.

Comment: Finally got back around to this project, @akmozo i tryed your script and it didnt work: / same exact error.. im really starting to think is this program:( dangit.

Comment: @akmozo ya it SWf quicker for sure. its not importing my action script after ive edited it. i put in nothing but a quote on one line ion the action script and it returned the same error. im gonna try and contact Sothink about the issue i guess.

Answer (score 0):

I saw the SWF Quicker and think it is a disaster !!

In any case, try this :

```
intrinsic class SliderTrack_Terminator extends MovieClip
{

    public function SliderTrack_Terminator()
    {
        return;
    }

}
```